# redirect after 5 seconds of ajax form submission jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am submiting form like

```
$(this).parents("form").ajaxForm(options);
```

how can I set timeout? mean I want to redirect page after 5 seconds of form submission

Comment: `how can I set timeout?` -->  with `setTimeout()` :)

Comment: `setTimeout(()=>{location.replace("newurl")}, 5000)`

Comment: You have to use `success` paramaeter of option. Where you can do your timeout activity.

Comment: actually I want to redirect if no success response received. like if there is timeout error on php side

Comment: @GulzarAli: The options being passed to `.ajaxForm()` also include an `error` handler function.

Answer (score 0):

So set success and use a timeout

```
$("#foo").ajaxForm({
    success: function(res, status, xhr, form) {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
          window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: `location.href = ...` is not a redirect. `location.replace(...)` is.

Comment: It sure is. Try it in your console.

Comment: So you want to not allow back using replace?

Comment: If the downvote was for the somewhat semantic difference in how to redirect in JavaScript, there [is information about that too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/328193).

Comment: It is not a redirect. It's a navigation. If you press the back button you go to the page that used `location.href`. A redirect replaces the entry in the history stack.

Comment: @D.Pardal potato/potato - most people would call `location.href=` a "redirect".  Very few people would call it a "navigation".   "A redirect replaces the history stack" - can you back that up with evidence?  Most people asking questions on here would call this a "replace", not a "redirect" (at least in javascript questions).  IMO OP is clearly asking about moving to a new url (navigate in your parlance) not "replacing" the URL.